# IN ADF inside zip files are storing with default names as data_<> name. i need to make it as zipfile name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My source is sql db and sink is blob.
I need to store the file with zip and inside that name should be as cust_yyymmdd.csv
how can i get this in DATA FACTORY. when I tried I got like as shown below.
inside name should be as zip file name.

[FILE GENERATED AS SHOWN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSZ2n.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating a ZIP file to copy SQL data to blob as below.

- Parameterized the filename with .zip `@concat('Material_UOM_T006A_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhssmm'),'.zip’)` and compression type as ZipDeflate (.zip).

[image]

- When the pipeline is run, the Zip folder got generated with the given format but the file inside the folder is named as the table name but not the same as the folder name.

[image]

As a workaround, I have first copied the SQL data to blob folder with .csv extension and with customize the file name and added another copy activity to create zip folder with same file name and copied the generated csv file in previous copy activity to zip as below.

- Created a variable to store the file name using set variable activity and use the variable in later activities to generate filename dynamically.
- **Parameterize** the sink file name by creating the dataset parameter and pass the customized file name value in Sink settings as below.

[image]

`@concat('Material_UOM_T006A_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddhhssmm'),'.csv')`

[image]

- In second copy activity, copy the generated .csv file to .zip file.

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Niharika file name is generating ok but that should be inside zip

Comment: here u r generating separate file

Comment: Hi, Updated my answer with new details, please check.